# Does innerHTML impact on performance?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating this small app, the idea is to create something similar to a message board. I'm using `<li>` elements as container for each message. Anytime an user submits a new message, it gets added to the `<ul>` list. My `<li>` elements are formatted to have a certain style. Is the use of the innerHTML method a good choice?

At moment I'm using the Element.innerHTML method to add the full chunk of code, and all works fine.

```
const messageForm = document.querySelector("#message-form")
const messageTextarea = document.querySelector("#message-textarea");
const messageList = document.querySelector("#message-list");

const messageFormatted = messageText => {
  return `
  <li class="message-item">
    <img class="message-avatar" src="./icons/boy.png" alt="Username">
      <article class="message-content">
        <p>${messageText}</p>
      </article>
      <div class="message-actions">
        <img class="action-button" src="./icons/edit.png" alt="" width="22" height="22">
        <img class="action-button" src="./icons/delete.png" alt="" width="22" height="22">
      </div>
  </li>
  `;
}

messageForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (messageTextarea.value !== "") {
    messageList.innerHTML += messageFormatted(messageTextarea.value);
    messageTextarea.value = "";
    messageTextarea.focus();
  }
})
```

As you can see my `messageFormatted()` function returns a template that will eventually be added in the html list.

Am I using `Element.innerHTML` correctly? Or should I use JavaScript DOM methods, like `document.createElement()`, `Element.setAttribute()` etc..? There is any impact on performances with my code? And also, if this code is good, will it still be good if the code to inject was bigger? I know that good practice is to separate JavaScript from the view as mush as possible.

Comment: In modern browsers (like, browsers since 2009 or earlier even), `.innerHTML` is insanely fast.

Comment: You don't need to use createElement(). You can go ahead with your code, It is written in very good manner.

Comment: Using `.innerHTML` causes that DOM node to be rebuilt and the DOM to be reparsed. It can wipe out event handlers set on the contents being replaced and opens up security holes. It should be avoided when possible. Instead, build new elements using the DOM API and insert them into the DOM with that API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine the way you do it, but i would suggest the use of, at least to me, a much cleaner way of `Element.insertAdjacentHTML()`

About performance it's about the same for `Element.innerHTML` and `Element.insertAdjacentHTML()`, but the first one is a property the second is a method.For more complex structures you gain a lot more of performance from `Element.insertAdjacentHTML()` as explained on MDN, see link i did provide.

About security i would like to mention that `Element.innerHTML` is discouraged by a notable amount of people, because it can corrupt the existing elements.

My suggestion is to change 2 lines.

```
messageForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (messageTextarea.value !== "") {
    messageList.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", messageFormatted(messageTextarea.value)); //use of insertAdjacentHTML
    messageTextarea.value = null; //empty
    messageTextarea.focus();
  }
})
```

[Element.insertAdjacentHtml() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Comment: Thank you so much, I read about insertAdjacentHtml() from the link you provided. And I got what you mean. Thank you!

Comment: @RavenMask you are welcome, feel free to comment with any questions you may have.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't try any benchmark but, anyway, if the code to inject is bigger, your code will be very difficult to read if you use functions like createElement(), setAttribute().

So using your current approach is simpler to read.